# How to write rspec test for custom routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have the following custom route:

```
match '/boeing-737', controller: :planes, action: :display, id: 1000
```

The 'get' method in rspec only accepts action name, but doing this:

```
get :display, id: 1000
```

I am getting:

**RoutingError: No route matches {:id=>"1000", :controller=>"planes", :action=>"display"}**

And there is no option to do get '/boeing-737' in the test.

Comment: Please post your controller code.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution, the id has to be string value, I will post it here since I think this use case is not documented enough in rspec:

```
match '/boeing-737', controller: :planes, action: :display, id: '1000'
```